# How to change the heap size in Prometheus

Tags: size, heap-memory, prometheus

I'm trying to change the heap size of my prometheus docker application.

The documentation states here https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/1.8/storage/ that there is a flag called `storage.local.target-heap-size`. Well surprise, there is no such flag when listing the prometheus flags with `prometheus -h` inside the docker container.

Furthermore there isn't a single explanation on how to change any configuration at all.
Then I found this video the documentation was linking to from Björn Rabenstein, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPC60ldCGm8

Here he is talking for 35 Minutes on what these flags are for and how they work ( note that the heap size flag didn't exist at that time ) but never even once shows an example on how to change the configuration.

This is the most infuriating documentation with no examples on how to change configurations I have ever seen. And I'm 100% sure that I'm not the only one and many other people just wish to see a simple example on how to change those configs.

So I'm asking here, does anyone have an idea on how to change the heap size in prometheus?

Thank you in advance

Comment: That flag and the documentation url you mentioned are for previous versions. If you switch to the 2.x versions, you can see that memory section is gone. Reading these two threads in mailing list can be helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prometheus-users/K-63dBkJwuY and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prometheus-users/Db8NZf6dfao